# Install package using npm

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to install npm using :

```
sudo npm install azure@0.6.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/azure/0.6.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/azure/0.6.9

npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: azure@0.6.9
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.6.15"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-31-virtual
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "azure@0.6.9"
npm ERR! cwd /home/azureuser/nvm/bin
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! message Unsupported
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/azureuser/nvm/bin/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
$ node --version
v0.8.16
```

not sure where it is getting the version number from (or) why is the use in nvm also not taking into effect. Can you please let me know what I am missing

Comment: try this command `sudo node --version` and see what it gives you. It might be that root has one version of node and your use has access to another.

Comment: It depends where you installed your ``nvm``. If you did not use ``sudo`` to install it, don't ``sudo`` your ``npm install``, as npm will put the files within nvm installation.